# Why is GCC with __attribute__((__ms_abi__)) returning values differently than MSVC does?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, calling-convention, abi

[x86 Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) in the GCC documentation says this:

> On 32-bit and 64-bit x86 targets, you can use an ABI attribute to indicate which calling convention should be used for a function. The `ms_abi` attribute tells the compiler to use the Microsoft ABI, while the `sysv_abi` attribute tells the compiler to use the System V ELF ABI, which is used on GNU/Linux and other systems. The default is to use the Microsoft ABI when targeting Windows. On all other systems, the default is the System V ELF ABI.

But consider this C code:

```c
#include <assert.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define MS_ABI
#else
#define MS_ABI __attribute__((__ms_abi__))
#endif

typedef struct {
    void *x, *y;
} foo;

static_assert(sizeof(foo) == 8, "foo must be an 8-byte structure");

foo MS_ABI f(void *x, void *y) {
    foo rv;
    rv.x = x;
    rv.y = y;
    return rv;
}
```

`gcc -O2 -m32` compiles it to this:

```
f:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], edx
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+4], edx
        ret
```

But `cl /O2` compiles it to this:

```
_x$ = 8                                       ; size = 4
_y$ = 12                                                ; size = 4
_f      PROC                                                ; COMDAT
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]
        ret     0
_f      ENDP
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/3qP1Ea55M)

These are clearly using incompatible calling conventions. [Argument Passing and Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=msvc-170) on MSDN says this:

> Return values are also widened to 32 bits and returned in the EAX register, except for 8-byte structures, which are returned in the EDX:EAX register pair. Larger structures are returned in the EAX register as pointers to hidden return structures.

Which means MSVC is correct. So why is GCC using the pointer-to-hidden-return-structure approach even though the return value is an 8-byte structure? Is this a bug in GCC, or am I not allowed to use `ms_abi` like I think I am?

Comment: That seems buggy to me.  i386 SysV only returns `int64_t` in registers, not structs of the same size, but perhaps GCC forgot to take that into account for `ms_abi`.  It doesn't in general change struct layouts in cases where that differs, or for x86-64 make `long` a 32-bit type, but your struct does have the same layout in both ABIs, so you'd expect it to get returned the way an MSVC caller wants.  But that's not happening.  `gcc -mabi=ms` doesn't help either.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was enough to convince me that it is a bug (in particular that `-mabi=ms` does it too), so I opened [#105932](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105932) about it. If you summarize your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems buggy to me. i386 SysV only returns `int64_t` in registers, not structs of the same size, but perhaps GCC forgot to take that into account for `ms_abi`.  Same problem with gcc `-mabi=ms` ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mabi-6)).

Even `-mabi=ms` doesn't in general change struct layouts in cases where that differs, or for x86-64 make `long` a 32-bit type.  But your struct does have the same layout in both ABIs, so you'd expect it to get returned the way an MSVC caller wants. But that's not happening.

This is IIRC not the first time I've heard of bugs in `__attribute__((ms_abi))` or `-mabi=ms`. But you are using it correctly; in 64-bit code that would make the difference to which arg-passing registers it looked in.

Clang makes the same asm as GCC, but that's not significant because it warns that *the 'ms_abi' calling convention is not supported for this target*. This is the asm we'd expect from i386 SysV. (And Godbolt doesn't have clang-cl.)

---

So thanks for reported it to GCC as [bug #105932](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105932).

(Funny that when it chooses to use SSE or AVX, it loads both dword stack args separately and shuffles them together, instead of a `movq` load.  I guess that avoids likely store-forwarding stalls if the caller didn't use a single 64-bit store to write the args, though.)

Comment: Isn't the stack only required to be 4-byte aligned on 32-bit Windows, so couldn't `movq` end up being misaligned if it got used?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: That's true, but it's still probably worth it for throughput, especially on Skylake and newer where a page split isn't a disaster.  Loads narrower than 16 bytes never require alignment so there's no correctness problem.  And besides, GCC targeting 32-bit Windows may still *aim* to align the stack by 16, I think, with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4`, only getting less alignment in callback functions, or in shared library functions called from a main executable that doesn't align the stack.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: It stores the return-value object with `movq` even though `alignof(struct foo)` is only 4.